# Installation error phonegap in ubuntu

Tags: json, node.js, ubuntu, cordova, npm

I am trying to install phonegap in ubuntu 12.04. Using [this](http://phonegap.com/install/) instraction. But there was an error,

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/1.3.7
npm http 500 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/1.3.7
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/1.3.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/1.3.7
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-51-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "update" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/mridul
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mridul/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for me was to run `make test` from the node.js folder. This identified that Curl was missing from my system.

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: Thanks.. I reinstall the curl. Now it work!! First remove the current curl "sudo apt-get autoremove curl " then install it "sudo apt-get install curl"